# IntelliJ refuses to setup Gradle JVM: Found invalid Gradle JVM configuration

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have the following problem: I try to setup IntelliJ to use my local Gradle installation but when IDEA starts I get the following error message after importing my project:

```
Found invalid Gradle JVM configuration
```

`gradle jar` works perfectly fine on the command line.

The workaround is to manually do the following:

1. Find action -> Search -> Gradle -> Then select 'Gradle JVM:' option on the popup
2. Override 'Use Gradle from:' and choose 'Specificed location' (In my case /home/jose/local/gradle/gradle-4.10.3)
3. Override 'Gradle JVM:' and choose 'JAVA_HOME' (Shows up correctly as 'version 1.8.0_282')
4. Click 'Apply' and 'OK'. Restart IntelliJ

But reading the documentation about the [Gradle settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-settings.html) and [Gradle JVM selection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-jvm-selection.html) says than IntelliJ will honor the following settings for the gradle wrapper properties (default choice):

- JAVA_HOME (Defined to /opt/myjdkhome/1.8.0_282)
- GRADLE_USER_HOME (Defined to $HOME/.gradle)
- I'm using IntelliJ Idea Community Edition 2021.2.2

And more important, I do have the following overrides on the $HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties

```java
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
org.gradle.daemon=false
org.gradle.java.home=/opt/myjdkhome/1.8.0_282
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.company.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.company.com
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.company.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.company.com
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=XXXX
# systemProp.javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake
```

The gradle wrapper property file, gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties (generated with `gradle wrapper`) is pretty vanilla:

```java
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Any ideas? I was thinking about dropping a XML partial configuration on $PROJECT_ROOT/.idea/gradle.xml but not sure if this will work. There is a way to override that for ALL the projects?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="GradleSettings">
    <option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
      <GradleProjectSettings>
        <option name="delegatedBuild" value="true" />
        <option name="testRunner" value="GRADLE" />
        <option name="distributionType" value="LOCAL" />
        <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
        <option name="gradleHome" value="$USER_HOME$/local/gradle/gradle-4.10.3" />
        <option name="gradleJvm" value="#JAVA_HOME" />
        <option name="modules">
          </set>
        </option>
      </GradleProjectSettings>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-269983). Please follow for updates.

Comment: Hi, any updates on this ? It's still going on